# Pydev unable to properly detect instance type through transitive property

Tags: python, pydev

In PyCharm (does it use PyDev in the background?) as well as PTVS, the transitive property for instance types seems to work well.  For example:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        '''
        :type name: str
        :type age: int
        '''
        self.Name = name  # `name` is str, therefore IDE detects self.Name as type string
        self.Age = age
```

Since `name` is of type str, PyCharm and PTVS successfully detect `self.Name` as type string and you can code complete its methods.

However, I cannot get this working properly in PyDev.  PyDev seems to have no clue what type `self.Name` is, therefore failing to autocomplete it.  Am i missing an important setting for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was a glitch in the PyDev type inference engine. This is now fixed in git: https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/commit/dd167df9960171dd0a05679804df157f4f6886bf and will be available for PyDev 4.4.0.